# Firebase analytics not tracking on iOS App

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have implemented Firebase analytics onto the iOS app. When I simulate the app through Xcode, Firebase is able to track this within DebugView. The changes have been pushed to live and after a couple of days no analytics have been tracked. I have checked the App Analytics through iTunes Connect and it shows the app has been downloaded and active.

Is there anything I may have missed?

Comment: Do you have any Development/Release versions by any chance?

Comment: No, both versions are the same.

Comment: Would you be able to see any real-time traffic from released app in StreamView?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't seem to be tracking anything from the live app. Although when looking at the dashboard its tracking the Xcode simulation. I thought it only tracked live app data.

Comment: The DebugView will display the traffic in development. StreamView will display the traffic from released apps in the wild. Are you looking at StreamView or DebugView?

Comment: I can see development traffic within DebugView. The development traffic also seems to appear in the dashboard (after 24 hours). The data that appears on the dashboard matches the development traffic. No traffic is displayed on StreamView. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is strange. I'd recommend to contact Firebase Support with your app ID so they can look further into it.

Comment: Just came across the same issue, did you manage to get it sorted ?